# Why does the eigenvalue $-1$ have even multiplicity for all the conjugacy classes in these representations?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

I have been conducting some experiments with GAP and have noticed a pattern which I would like to disregard as a coincidence or explain theoretically. Consider a finite group $G$ and a representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $C$ be a conjugacy class in $G$. For any $g,h\in C$, the characteristic polynomials of the associated matrices in the representation are the same, so we can write $E_C$ for the associated list of eigenvalues. For many groups I have tried, with the aid of GAP, the multiplicity $m(E_C)$ of the eigenvalue $-1$ always seems to be even for all conjugacy classes $C$. I cannot see if that is just a coincidence or not. I have used a variety of representations available in the Atlas, for example, http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/clas/U42/. For the representation of dimension $15$ of the unitary group $U_4(2)$ listed there, $m(E_C)\in\{0,2,4,8\}$. For a representation of dimension $6$ of the alternating group $A_7$, $m(E_C)\in\{0,2\}$. For a representation of dimension $11$ of the linear group $L_2(11)$, $m(E_C)\in\{0,2,6\}$. I have experimented with a number of other groups, with similar results, but cannot explain the persistence of even multiplicities.

Comment: To make sure: you are not interested in the non-trivial 1-dimensional representation of the cyclic group of order two :-) Elements of the center act as scalars, so whenever you have an irrreducible representation of odd dimension, and the group has elements of order two in its center, you can expect a counterexample. Of course, it is still possible that the said central element is in the kernel of that rep.

Comment: Yes, you guessed right, the non-trivial 1-dimensional representation of the cyclic group of order two was not of interest :-) Thanks for the other remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the representation is defined over $\mathbb R$ (so, in particular, if it defined over $\mathbb Q$), then whenever $\zeta$ is an eigenvalue of $g\in G$, so is $\overline{\zeta} = \zeta^{-1}$ (and with the same multiplicity). The only non-trivial root of unity which is equal to its own conjugate/inverse is $-1$.  Thus, the determinant of (the image of) $g$ is equal to $(-1)^{\text{mult. of $-1$ as an eigenvalue of }g}.$

Thus, the determinant of the given representation is trivial if and only if $-1$ always appears as an eigenvalue with trivial multiplicity.

If $G$ is perfect (so in particular if it is simple) then any representation will have trivial determinant, so $-1$ will always appear with even multiplicity in any rep'n that can be defined over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So simple. Taking advantage of the field of definition was not in my repertoire :-)